# How disable submit button after call OpenModalDialogCommand in Ajax callback?

Tags: ajax

I have a block that has a button, when pressing that button an ajax is triggered that shows a popup with the OpenModalDialogCommand event, after closing the popup I want to deactivate the submit button, does anyone know how to do that?

The form

```
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Get cupon'),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="cupon_form_wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#attributes' => $results > 0 ? array('disabled' => 'disabled') : [],
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => '::_modal_form_cupon_ajax_submit',
        'event' => 'click'
      ),
    );
```

```
function _modal_form_cupon_ajax_submit(array $form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    if ($form_state->getErrors()) {
      unset($form['#prefix']);
      unset($form['#suffix']);
      $form['status_messages'] = [
        '#type' => 'status_messages',
        '#weight' => -10,
      ];
      $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#cupon_form_wrapper', $form));
    }
    else {
      $content = 'Lorem ipsum';
      $title = 'Download';
      $response = new AjaxResponse();
      $response->addCommand(
        new OpenModalDialogCommand(
          $title,
          $content,
          array(
            'width'=>'300'
          )
        ),
        $form
      );
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its as simple as adding an extra Command to your AjaxResponse class.

Something like this should work. Make sure you change the css  selector (first argument) so it matches your button (or form).

```php
$response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('.button-selector', 'hide', []));
```

Comment: Thank you, you gave me a hint of how I should do it, I use this: 

$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Get cupon'),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="cupon_form_wrapper">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#attributes' => ['disabled' => 'disabled'],
      ); 

      $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#cupon_form_wrapper', $form));